# Por que esse código JavaScript não funciona?

Tags: javascript

Por que esse JavaScript não funciona?

Código JavaScript:

```
$('#basic_validate').submit(function(e) {
    document.getElementById('successmsg').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('errormsg').style.display = 'none';
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../suppliers/resources/controllers/register.php",
        async: true,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { 
        },
        complete: function(result){
            if(result == true){
                //clear inputs
                document.getElementById('successmsg').style.display = 'block';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('errormsg').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Código HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin">
//text_inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estás a fazer o submit por ajax tens de parar o submit por HTML.
Para isso tens de usar o [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Usa assim:

```
$('#frmLogin').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../controllers/insert.php",
        async: true,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { 
        },
        complete: function(result){
            if(result == 10)
                //clear inputs
                //show msg success
            else
                //show msg error
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tive um erro nessa linha data: $form.serialize(). No seu código tem um }); que eu removi entao o erro nao foi por isso

Comment: @Lucas pois, isso era uma das minhas perguntas no comentário anterior. Imagino que o que queiras seja `$(this).serialize()`. Corrigi na resposta.

Comment: Atualizei o post principal, funcionou mas nao consigo pegar o retorno. No caso do .php eu coloquei return true quando dá sucesso e return false quando dá erro @sergio

Comment: @Lucas faz `console.log(data);` dentro da função success, e `console.log(result);` dentro da função complete. Assim ficas a saber o que recebes. O que aparece na consola?

Comment: @Lucas faz `console.log(data);` dentro da função success, e `console.log(result);` dentro da função complete. Assim ficas a saber o que recebes. O que aparece na consola?